# Android Connection is made but no Object is sent

Tags: android, networking, object

I am trying to send an object to a server i wrote. I have only just learnt about AsyncTask and am trying to use it in order to keep networking tasks off the main thread. It is currently making the connection but is not receiving the object. I know the server is fine because I have tested it using code written to send the object from my laptop. Also I am not receiving any error messages.

Code:

```
private class sendToServer extends AsyncTask<UserObject, Integer, Double> {
    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(UserObject...userObjects) {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        String Header = "GPSUpdate";
        String Userid = "07000000001";
        String Latitude = "6.00";
        String Longitude = "6.00";

        try{
            Socket socket = new Socket("igor.gold.ac.uk", 3000);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            UserObject [] userObject = new UserObject[1];
            userObject[0] = new UserObject();
            userObject[0].setHeader(Header);
            userObject[0].setUserid(Userid);
            userObject[0].setLatitude(Latitude);
            userObject[0].setLongitude(Longitude);

            oos.writeObject(userObject[0]);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
    }
}
```

Also the code to send the object works when ran from my laptop. Do I have to set permissions or anything different if I'm using AsyncTask to handle network operations.

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty block catching *all* exceptions! At least log what's going on in there...

1. Does your app have the INTERNET permission declared in its manifest?
2. Does UserObject implement Serializable?

Comment: I have printed from the catch and there appears to be no errors being produced.

I have already declared INTERNET in the manifest and it does implement Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it was my own simple mistake. All the code was fine but the Object being sent was in a different package on the server than the one being sent. Updated them so they are both in the same package in their respective location.